# Scaling an image and place it in the specific location (coordinates) in Android's LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, bitmap, scaling

I'm not very skilled in android application developing, and I'm working on a test app. I detected the face and the eyes, now I'm going to draw something like acne or scar on the face (e.g below the eyes on the cheek) based on the coordinates of the eyes. Later, I'm going to put eye-glass or hat on the appropriate locations.

I know the coordinates of the left and the right eye (leftEyePosx... [and so on] in the code). For example 136x168 [left] and 216x168 [right] (mirrored in picture). Now, I'm calculating the scale: glass bitmap should be scaled around 80 pixels (216-136) or bigger for the width, and 80 pixels multiplied with the original image's aspect ratio for the height (e.g. 80 * 0.7). I have the bitmap with the code:

```
glassBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.glass_01);
```

Now, how can I re-scale the eye-glass and use the method canvas.drawBitmap() and use eye coordinates and draw the glass on the face? Or should I use another way?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you scale the bitmaps:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
```

Then you draw one bitmap on top of the other, at xPos and yPos:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(baseBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, xPos, yPos, paint);
```

xPos and yPos are the upper left corner of the overlay bitmap. For example, if the base image eye is supposed to show in the middle of the overlay bitmap, you have to adjust for this by deducting half the width and height to find the desired xPos and yPos.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Karlsson, will ya answer the updated Q? tnx.

Comment: Post a new question, not edit the old answered question. Suggest you specify what you mean by "not working" in the new question.

Comment: OK. I thought it may be considered as a duplicate.